# Multiple vars fails in scope tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, scoping

Hello I have in my document a repeating figure of a bar like thing.
So i want create a scope with 4 parameters. x and y from center point and dx dy displacements. (later on maybe color but that's maybe another question)

I start with the basic tikzfigure with a scope in it. after that i create the `newcommand{}{}`.
add the parameters it starts failing.
I have try to figure out where it (starts) breaks(breaking).
With a single parameter it works well(`barfig`). But whit adding the second parameter(`bargigg`) is fails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, snakes, calc}


\newcommand{\barfig}[1]
{%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0 cm,0 cm)}]
        \draw (- #1,-1.5) rectangle (#1, 1.5);
%       3D
        \draw (- #1,1.5) -- (- #1, 1.5,-1.5) ;
        \draw (- #1,-1.5) -- (- #1, -1.5,-1.5) ;
        \draw (#1,1.5) -- (#1, 1.5,-1.5) ;
        \draw (#1,-1.5) -- (#1, -1.5,-1.5) ;
        \draw[thick, red, dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 8pt off 3pt] (0,1.5+0.5) --(0,-1.5-0.5);
        \draw[thick, red, dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 8pt off 3pt] (#1+0.5,0) --(- #1 -0.5,0);
        \fill[blue] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt] node[above right] {$D$};
    \end{scope}
}


\newcommand{\barfigg}[2]
{%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0 cm,0 cm)}]
        \draw (- #1,- #2) rectangle (#1, #2);
        %       3D
        \draw (- #1, #2) -- (- #1, #2, -1.5) ;
        \draw (- #1, -#2) -- (- #1, - #2, -1.5) ;
        \draw (#1, #2) -- (#1, #2, -1.5) ;
        \draw (#1,- #2) -- (#1, - #2, -1.5) ;
        \draw[thick, red, dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 8pt off 3pt] (0,#2 +0.5) --(0,- #2-0.5);
        \draw[thick, red, dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 8pt off 3pt] (#1+0.5,0) --(- #1 -0.5,0);
        \fill[blue] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt] node[above right] {$D$};
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \barfig{1};
        \barfigg{1, 1.5};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody explain what goes wrong? Or maybe better what do i wrong...

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the command with the wrong syntax, you should use:

`\barfigg{1}{1.5}`

is the correct one: albeit `tikz` uses key-value pairs for its optional parameters, a command with two mandatory arguments accepts them in separated balanced curly braces pairs.

This is valid for all commands and mandatory parameters number.

Using then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, snakes, calc}


\newcommand{\barfig}[1]
{%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0 cm,0 cm)}]
        \draw (- #1,-1.5) rectangle (#1, 1.5);
%       3D
        \draw (- #1,1.5) -- (- #1, 1.5,-1.5) ;
        \draw (- #1,-1.5) -- (- #1, -1.5,-1.5) ;
        \draw (#1,1.5) -- (#1, 1.5,-1.5) ;
        \draw (#1,-1.5) -- (#1, -1.5,-1.5) ;
        \draw[thick, red, dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 8pt off 3pt] (0,1.5+0.5) --(0,-1.5-0.5);
        \draw[thick, red, dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 8pt off 3pt] (#1+0.5,0) --(- #1 -0.5,0);
        \fill[blue] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt] node[above right] {$D$};
    \end{scope}
}


\newcommand{\barfigg}[2]
{%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0 cm,0 cm)}]
        \draw (- #1,- #2) rectangle (#1, #2);
        %       3D
        \draw (- #1, #2) -- (- #1, #2, -1.5) ;
        \draw (- #1, -#2) -- (- #1, - #2, -1.5) ;
        \draw (#1, #2) -- (#1, #2, -1.5) ;
        \draw (#1,- #2) -- (#1, - #2, -1.5) ;
        \draw[thick, red, dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 8pt off 3pt] (0,#2 +0.5) --(0,- #2-0.5);
        \draw[thick, red, dash pattern=on 2pt off 3pt on 8pt off 3pt] (#1+0.5,0) --(- #1 -0.5,0);
        \fill[blue] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt] node[above right] {$D$};
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \barfig{1};
        \barfigg{1}{1.5};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]